# Creating random button collect in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on project and in first page of my application is a block that shows one of the posts in random order, but there is also a button to refresh this random post and show another instead without user needs to refresh the page.

Now my question is, how to make that button works?

Here is my controller:

```
public function index() {
      $randomfood = Food::where('status', 1)->inRandomOrder()->take(1)->get();
      return view('welcome', compact('randomfood'));
}
```

This is my view:

```
@foreach($randomfood as $randfood)
         <div class="col-md-2"><a href="{{ route('showrecipe', $food->slug) }}"><img src="{{url('/')}}/images/{{$randfood->image}}" class="thumbnail img-responsive" alt="food image"></a></div>
         <div class="col-md-8">
              <h5><a href="{{ route('showrecipe', $food->slug) }}">{{$randfood->title}}</a></h5>
              {!!  str_limit($randfood->description, 100) !!}
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
              <p>Don't like?</p>
              <a class="bhover" href="#">Find another recipie</a>
         </div>
@endforeach
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

JS code now is like this after checked from http://www.jslint.com/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$( "a.bhover" ).click(function() {
$.ajax({
          url: "{{route('food.randompost')}}",
          data: {"token_": "{{Session::token()}}"}, //session token, neccesary to use POST request
          type: "food",
          success: function (data) {
             $("#live_content").empty(); //clean the actual post
             $("#live_content").append(data); // add new post from the controller
          },
          error: function(data){
              //handle errors here
          }
      });
});
});
});
```

Error in console:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'[Learn More]
```

Comment: Use Ajax call to refresh the random post.

Comment: @SagarGautam can you help me how to do it?

Comment: Since you know about the logic to get random post from database. When button is clicked, you have to detect event of button click in javascript and make ajax call to a route which will call a function. In the function you need to write code to get random post and return the random post as json response from function. After this, on success function of ajax, you have to write code to refresh current post data in html with data from json response. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to do here is:

```
public function index() {
      $randomfood = Food::where('status', 1)->inRandomOrder()->first();
      return view('welcome', compact('randomfood'));
}
```

So you can use your random food post as a single element instead of as collection. Let's add a div which wraps the desired live element to make it live:

```
<div id="live_content">
                  <div class="col-md-2"><a href="{{ route('showrecipe', $food->slug) }}"><img src="{{url('/')}}/images/{{$randomfood ->image}}" class="thumbnail img-responsive" alt="food image"></a></div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h5><a href="{{ route('showrecipe', $food->slug) }}">{{$randomfood->title}}</a></h5>
                      {!!  str_limit($randomfood->description, 100) !!}
                  </div>
</div>
                  <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                      <p>Don't like?</p>
                      <a class="bhover" href="#">Find another recipie</a>
                  </div>
```

Okey now, let's create a blade view to fill with the refreshed data, i.e. `live.recipe.blade.php`:

```
 <div class="col-md-2"><a href="{{ route('showrecipe', $food->slug) }}"><img src="{{url('/')}}/images/{{$randomfood ->image}}" class="thumbnail img-responsive" alt="food image"></a></div>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <h5><a href="{{ route('showrecipe', $food->slug) }}">{{$randomfood->title}}</a></h5>
                          {!!  str_limit($randomfood->description, 100) !!}
                      </div>
```

We need a route and a method to handle the ajax call in our controller so let's add it:

web.php

```
Route::post('update-post', 'YourController@updateRandomPost')->name('food.randompost');
```

Controller

```
public function updateRandomPost(Request $request) {
      $randomfood = Food::where('status', 1)->inRandomOrder()->first(); // get new random post
      return view('live.recipe', compact('randomfood')); //fill our live post template and retrieve it to the view
}
```

We gonna call this method by using an ajax call, add it on your scripts sections inside the view. Add a bind to the button's click action too:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
    $( "a.bhover" ).click(function() {
      $.ajax({
                url: '{{route('food.randompost')}}', //our fresh route name
                data: {"token_": '{{Session::token()}}'}, //session token, neccesary to use POST request
                type: 'post',
                success: function (data) {
                   $('#live_content').empty(); //clean the actual post
                   $('#live_content').append(data); // add new post from the controller
                },
                error: function(data){
                    //handle errors here
                }
            });
    });

    });
</script>
```

And that's all IMO, let me know if you don't undersand something

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153795/discussion-on-answer-by-aaron0207-creating-random-button-collect-in-laravel-5-5).